# Population Growth; Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

The population of a certain community is known to increase at a rate proportional to the number of people present at time $t$. Suppose it is known that the population of the community is $10,000$ after $3$ years. What was the initial population? What will be the population in $10$ years? How fast is the population growing at $t = 30$?

Here is what I have so far:

$P'(t)$ prop $P(t)$ therefore $P'(t) = kP(t)$

$P'(t)-kP(t) = 0$  and $\mu = e^{-kt}$

$P(t)  = Ce^{kt}$

Plugging in $P(3) = 10,000$

$10000 = Ce^{3k}$

Therefore $C = 10,000e^{-3k}$

Thus $P(t) = 10,000e^{-3k}*e^{kt}$

How do I solve for $k$? 
It seems like this question is lacking some additional information.... $P_3 = 10,0000$ $P_0 = ?$

I really have no idea how to get here? Most everything else says the population increases at a rate $5$ times $P_0$ or  something similar. Not this one.

Then there is $P(t) = P_0e^{rt}$ but $P_0$ must $= 0$ and that is not given. Or would I use this equation with $10,000 = P_0e^{3r}$ but that again leads me to I still do not have $r$.

****About 4 hours before this assignment was due the prof added the addendum: the population is 2,000 after 1 year; that is P(1) = 2,000.

Comment: You do need more information to answer the questions. Also, taking the words literally, " population (...) increase at a rate proportional to the number of people" actually means $\frac{P'(t)}{P(t)}=kP(t)$.

Comment: About 4 hours before the assignment was due, my prof added P(1) = 2000.

Comment: Can you solve this now?

Comment: Yes. I ended up with k = (ln 5)/2, so P_0 is about equal to 894 people.